How to set GridView Cell Background color
I would want to set the back ground color of a cell based on the bound Burshdata, but it does not fill the whole cell.
The image demonstrating my problem:

Here is my code:
<GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                       Foreground="{Binding FontColor}"
                       Background="{Binding BackGroundColor}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <GridViewColumn.Header>Csapatnév</GridViewColumn.Header>
</GridViewColumn>


I think the TextBlock may have no reference  to "Stretch" to. You may need to specify a "Width"; or, put the TextBlock in a "Container" that it can stretch to (e.g. a "stretched" Grid that responds to the column width?)

By default, GridViewColumn cells have an alignment of HorizontalContentAlignment=Left.
Unfortunately, it is not possible to set an individual alignment value for each column.
But you can set the same value for all columns:
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

